# Is there a way to see app feedback I've sent on Android?

Tags: google-hangouts, feedback

Yesterday I sent some feedback for an app (Google Hangouts) through Android's system-wide *Send Feedback* function. This is the same dialog box that is triggered when you choose to report a Force Close. See screenshots below.

I realised later that I had no internet connection at the time, and so the feedback may not have been sent. This made me wonder: is there any way to see every feedback item and crash report that I've sent to specific apps?

For the record, I'm running CyanogenMod 10.1 (Jelly Bean 4.2.2) on an HTC Sensation.

[image: How to trigger the Send Feedback Dialog in Google Hangouts.]
[image: Send Feedback dialog.]

Comment: actually this is not the exact same dialog of reporting about crashes, since the bottom part( just above the buttons) isn't there. however, it's a good question and as a developer i didn't even find out how to show it like this, and i've posted about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528809/how-to-show-the-send-feedback-to-x-dialog

Answer (score 2):

It looks like *you* can't send Google Feedback reports to specific apps (although, as Dan Hulme commented, Google does forward them to the developers of the app on which you are reporting) - as you said, it's a system-wide option. You can visit https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/reports?hl=en to view feedback reports that you have submitted while logged into a certain Google account. However, I have not been able to find anything on viewing crash reports themselves that you or your device have sent, automatically or otherwise.

Comment: That's not true: the reports get shown to the developer of the faulty app.

Comment: Yes, but you don't send it to them directly or specifically. Google and its Developer Console handle that, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 1):

No, as of November 16th, 2014, Google has not provided a method of reviewing and/or checking past crash reports. While this may be available in future references, reports are sent solely to development teams.